# Azure Logic app - Send the whole email to a rest call as a .eml attachment

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a logic app with email received trigger.

When email has multiple attachments, I am able to loop and make a http call per attachment

However we have to send the whole email as http call by creating .eml file of the email with attachments.

Pls advise

Answer (score 1):

While the built-in actions do not seem to support this out of the box, you can make a [Microsoft Graph API call to get the MIME content of a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message#get-mime-content-of-an-outlook-message).

There is no official connector for all available Microsoft Graph APIs, so you would need to use the [HTTP with Azure AD Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/webcontents/) instead.

The response body content could then be written to a file in blob storage using the [Create Blob Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#create-blob).